# I want the isset to include a same variable in both S_GET variables.

Tags: php

For example, when you switch a site to a Jedi or Sith theme, you will also include still the same `$color2` in both Jedi and Sith themes, without needing the same variable in both themes.

Similar:

```
if (isset($_GET['jedi'])) 
{
  $color = "#299CF5";
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color = "#f45341";
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}
```

It should be like:

```
if (isset($_GET['jedi'])) 
{
  $color = "#299CF5";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color = "#f45341";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['jedi']) || isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}
```

In HTML:

```
<h3>Change your favourite theme of<span style="color: <?php echo $color ?>">Star Wars</span> of <span style="color: <?php echo $color2 ?>"> Gustavo</span></h3> <br>

<a href="index.php&jedi">Jedi</a> <br>
<a href="index.php&sith">Sith</a> <br>

<?php echo $color; ?> <br>
<?php echo $color2; ?>
```

Output in the Sith theme:

```html
<h3>Change your favourite theme of <span style="color: #f45341">Star Wars</span> of <span style="color: #F456C2"> Gustavo</span></h3>
    
    <a href="index.php&jedi">Jedi</a> <br>
    <a href="index.php&sith">Sith</a> <br>
    <br>
    #f45341 <br>
    #F456C2
```

Output in the Jedi theme:

```html
<h3>Change your favourite theme of <span style="color: #299CF5">Star Wars</span> of <span style="color: #F456C2"> Gustavo</span></h3>
    
    <a href="index.php&jedi">Jedi</a> <br>
    <a href="index.php&sith">Sith</a> <br>
    <br>
    #299CF5 <br>
    #F456C2
```

I also tried:

```
elseif (!isset($_GET['jedi']) || isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}

elseif (!isset($_GET['jedi'], $_GET['sith']))
{
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['jedi'], $_GET['sith']))
{
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}
```

All these ways didn't detect the `$color2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you really need to do is change the 2nd code

```
if (isset($_GET['jedi'])) 
{
  $color = "#299CF5";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color = "#f45341";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['jedi']) || isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}
```

to

```
if (isset($_GET['jedi'])) 
{
  $color = "#299CF5";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color = "#f45341";
}

if (isset($_GET['jedi']) || isset($_GET['sith']))
{
  $color2 = "#F456C2";
}
```